# client_side_validation and date_picker - not working (Rails)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, client-side-validation

I am getting 'can't be blank' error even when I have a value.

Validation works fine if I manually enter the data in the field.

If I were to populate the date with date picker, it disable the submit button and I am not able to submit the form.

I am using JQuery date picker, Rails 3.2.6 and latest client_side_validation gem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are some closed issues for that on the ClientSideValidations github project. I suggest searching there for the answer.